# orderBy in hasOne relation doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have a table (`weathers`) with several thousands rows, 90000 +- at the moment, each one belonging to one location.

This table can have multiple rows belonging to one location, but I still want just one, the last one for a given location.

My model `Location` have this relation defined as:

```
...
public function last_weather() {
    return $this->hasOne(\App\Weather::class, 'id_location')->orderBy('weathers.id', 'DESC');
}
...
```

And on my controller I'm retrieving the `last_weather` like:

```
...
Location::with(['last_weather'])->findOrfail(1);
...
```

The strange thing is that this worked until I have 45000+- rows in the `weather` table, I have 3200 locations, and the last records for each location that are returned are on 40000+- rows (between id 40000 and 43000 +-, of the `weathers` table)

I have checked my DB and I have each location updated on the 80000's, but the relation are returning the data from the 40000's. This is not even the first or the last weather for each location.

Comment: Can you add `\DB::enableQueryLog();` before your query, and then `dd(\DB::getQueryLog())` after your query, and post the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in your Location model

```
public function weathers()
{
   return $this->hasMany(\App\Weather::class, 'id_location');
}

public function lastWeather()
{
   return $this->weathers()->latest()->first();
}
```

Then in your controller

```
$location = Location::findOrfail(1);
```

then you can access the last weather like this

```
$location->lastWeather();
```

**UPDATE**

Or you can adjust how you eager load weathers

```
$location = Location::with([
        'weathers' => function($query) {
            $query->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
        },
    ])
    ->findOrfail(1);
```

Comment: I would prefer to leave it like a relation, it's more flexible. I can just eager load, or select the collumns as want

Comment: I have added another way

Answer (score 1):

Order by will return all rows, to only return a single row for each matching condition you need to use Group by

I never used Laravel, but looking at your code I'm guessing your query should look like this:

`return $this->hasOne(\App\Weather::class, 'id_location')->groupBy('weathers.id', 'DESC');`

Comment: Can you post that, adapt my code on the Model to that please?

Comment: Ok, but how do I retrieve the last one? This is returning the first one

Comment: Either delete `DESC` from the end, or replace it with `ASC`

Comment: It gives an error if I leave the `DESC`, ` Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DESC' in 'group statement' (`